# In Git, How can I rebase + squash a branch that has multiple merge commits in it's history without cherry-picking onto a totally new branch

Tags: git, version-control, git-rebase, branching-and-merging, git-merge-conflict

**The Problem**

I want to be able to take a branch originally branched off master with multiple merges from the master so it appears as a single commit on the master.  We do this in order to take a developer's branch and produce a clean history in the master (once it has been tested).

I know how to this by creating a new branch off the tip of the master  (i.e. the "master" pointer ) and cherry-picking onto it (resolving conflicts as necessary, but it should be possible to do with the rebase command only (shouldn't it?).  The assumption here is that the master itself has not been rebased.

As an example I want to take the following history, below with branch master
and branch doodle:

***Original History***

```
  *  commit K, branch doodle, merge commit (conflicts)
 /|
* |  commit J, branch master, 
| |
| *  commit I, branch doodle
* |  commit H, branch master
| |
| *  commit G, branch doodle,merge commit (conflicts)
|/|
| *  commit F, branch doodle
* |  commit E, branch master
| |
| *  commit D, branch doodle,merge commit (no conflicts)
|/|
* |  commit C, branch master
| *  commit B, Branch doodle 
|/
*    commit A, Branch master
```

And turn it into the following history on the master where the entire chain of commits on doodle are squashed and rebased onto the HEAD of master as shown below.  Since the head of branch doodle has commit K and all conflicts between master and doodle have been resolved, doing the below ought to be as easy as a single command. Also it does not mess with the history of the master that has been published.

***Desired History***

```
*    commit L, branch master,(squash commit B,D,F,G,I,K)
|
*    commit J, branch master
|
*    commit H, branch master
|
*    commit E, branch master
|
*    commit C, branch master
|
*    commit A, branch master
```

An alternate would be to generate the history shown below and than squash
commits B', F', G' I', J', K' before merging back to master.  This approach
below, however ,seems to add an extra step that rebase ought to be able to
handle (albiet with conflict resolution).

***Alternate History***

```
| *  commit K', branch doodle (possible conflict resolution)
| |
| *  commit I', branch doodle (possible conflict resolution)
| |
| *  commit G', branch doodle (possible conflict resolution)
| |
| *  commit F', branch doodle (possible conflict resolution)
| | 
| *  commit B', branch doodle (possible conflict resolution)
|/
*    commit K, branch master
|
*    commit H, branch master
| 
*    commit E, branch master
|
*    commit C, branch master
| 
*    commit A, Branch master
```

**What I have tried**

Currently I am creating a new branch off the master tip and cherry-picking B, F, and I onto it.  This works but is is more complicated than I believe is necessary as I have to re-resolve merge conflicts.  Now, I am aware of the `--rebase-merges` flag for `rebase`.  However, for some reason, I cannot get `--rebase-merges` to produce the "desire history" or even the alternate history.  Chances are I am selecting the commits with `rebase -i HEAD~N --rebase-merges` incorrectly.

**Question**

How can one easily easily go from original history to desired history?

Also, if the master in original history had a few extra commits after the last merge into doodle, will this approach allow for conflict resolution before pulling into master?

Answer (score 2):

This is easily done with `reset --soft`

```
git checkout doodle
git reset --soft master
git commit -m "doodle, as a single commit"
```

No hassle. If there are more commits into master that are *not* part of doodle, then merge before doing this.

Comment: I do have a follow minor detail I left off, but I did not realize it was that easy.  The detail I left off is I usually squash all the commits on the other branch (doodle in my example) together such that I leave the original time/date and author of that first commit in place to give the original author credit with the time/date the branch started.  Question:  Is there an additional command that can be executed to take the prior author's commit details for the first commit on doodle and apply it to the new commit you show above in your anwser eftshit0 .

Comment: Hmm.... I guess you could write a small script that can take care of those details. Getting the first revision that is _outside_ of master would be simple enough... then getting the name and email of that revision would not be that difficult... and then you can use `--author` when you do the commit after resetting.

Comment: @EmceeBC another thing you could do is make a new branch off master and cherry pick the first commit you want. Then run this answer but replace "master" with the new branch. Then change the commit to amend with all the changes.